# What is a good VIF threshold value?

Tags: data-science

I am trying to calculate the Variation inflation factor for continuous features. Here cnt is my target variable and variable in question is registered.

The registered variable has a high correlation(0.90) with cnt.
I have also added a constant value in my VIF test.

My question is should variable registered be removed from my dataset?
Also, what is an acceptable VIF threshold value?
There are many sources citing different vif threshold, a value that I came across most is 10.

Here is my code for Vif:

```
#Variation Inflation Factor
X = add_constant(data_num)
vif=pd.Series([variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])], index=X.columns)
```

Output:

```
const           50.091502
casual           2.004372
registered      10.598306
cnt             13.641529
hum_100          1.179175
atemp_50         2.155207
windspeed_67     1.107981
```